# Submit button in a partial view is invoking the POST action method of the main view.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Submit button in a partial view is invoking the POST action method of the main view. I want to invoke only the POST action method related to partial view and not the main view..

Answer (score 1):

Given the symptoms, this is most likely because you've placed your partial view inside of an existing `<form>` element from where you are rendering this partial view. e.g.

```
<form>
  @Html.RenderAction(...)
</form>
```

Whereat you are rendering another form and it's bubbling up to the top parent form.